# javax.ejb.EJBException: Could not load entity. JPA - glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

Hello I have an error when trying to fetch a list of customers from my EJB module, via an interface. 
my entity person says it cannot load. I tried to make a simple method to say hello, which goes through my layers backend, contract(interface) and frontend  - and this works fine.

this is the exception on glassfish server:

```
    WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[Controller]: Servlet.service() for servlet Controller threw exception
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446393 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810057: Could not load class entities.Person  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 57 completed: Maybe
    at contract._BankDataController_Wrapper.listCustomers(contract/_BankDataController_Wrapper.java)
    at commands.ListCustomersCommand.execute(ListCustomersCommand.java:20)
    at servlets.Controller.processRequest(Controller.java:59)
    at servlets.Controller.doGet(Controller.java:88)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446393 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810057: Could not load class entities.Person  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 57 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:266)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at contract.__BankDataController_Remote_DynamicStub.listCustomers(contract/__BankDataController_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810057: Could not load class entities.Person  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 57 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy201.couldNotFindClass(Unknown Source)
```

and my entity person:

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;


@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByFirstname", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.firstname = :firstname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByLastname", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.lastname = :lastname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByEmail", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByPhone", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.phone = :phone"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByCity", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.city = :city"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByZipcode", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.zipcode = :zipcode"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByStreet", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.street = :street"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByCountry", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.country = :country")})
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    //@NotNull
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seql")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seql", sequenceName = "PERSON_SEQ", initialValue = 1)
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 80)
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 80)
    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 80)
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    // @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;
    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;
    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(name = "ZIPCODE")
    private String zipcode;
    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(name = "STREET")
    private String street;
    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    private Employee employee;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private Collection<Account> accountCollection;
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "personCollection", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER ) 

    private Collection<Groups> groupsCollection;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void addGroup(Groups group){
        if (groupsCollection == null){
            groupsCollection= new ArrayList<>();
        }
        groupsCollection.add(group);  
    }

    public void addAccount(Account account){
        accountCollection.add(account);
    }

    public Person(Integer id, String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname, String email, String phone, String city, String zipcode, String street, String country, String password) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.city = city;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
        this.street = street;
        this.country = country;
        this.password = password;
    }



    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getZipcode() {
        return zipcode;
    }

    public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Account> getAccountCollection() {
        return accountCollection;
    }

    public void setAccountCollection(Collection<Account> accountCollection) {
        this.accountCollection = accountCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Person)) {
            return false;
        }
        Person other = (Person) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Collection<Groups> getGroupsCollection() {
        return groupsCollection;
    }

    public void setGroupsCollection(Collection<Groups> groupsCollection) {
        this.groupsCollection = groupsCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "id=" + id + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", email=" + email + ", phone=" + phone + ", city=" + city + ", zipcode=" + zipcode + ", street=" + street + ", country=" + country + ", employee=" + employee + ", accountCollection=" + accountCollection + ", password=" + password + ", groupsCollection=" + groupsCollection + '}';
    }



}
```

Comment: Seems like your client does not have the Person entity class on its classpath.

Comment: I am getting my person class through the contract. it is imported in the frontend...

Comment: @PerJohannessen: I am in the similar situation and already spent more than 1 day. Did you find any solution? please help!

Comment: Having the same issue. did you managed to solve this?